# 1007 entity is not mapped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this error: "1007 entity is not mapped" So I look in my edmx file and when I click "Validate", sure enough it says my two tables are not mapped to the database.

So I followed this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738478%28v=vs.103%29.aspx to map entities to DB tables that already exist, but when I get to step 2, my drop list is empty instead of what their direction says: "The field becomes a drop-down list that contains all the tables in the storage model that are not already included in the current mapping."

Article provides no comments on how to fix it if it's empty. Good ole MSDN! I haven't found anything online either so far.

Anyone know this one?

Comment: Right click an empty area in the edmx and choose update model from database.  That should take care of the mapping.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that before and it added my tables a second time so that I had duplicates, so I deleted them.  I tried again and it repeated that.  This time I updated the mapping on my original two (you were right that the drop list was populated now), then deleted the new pair of tables, and it seems good. Odd.  Thanks!